# How to zoom/pinch Total FrameLayout in ANDROID View Pager

Tags: android

I am working on View pager concept,Frame Layout is the inflated view for view pager adapter,In frame layout i have 4 imageviews to show on every view pager page,Now how to zoom/pinch total view pager having 4 imageviews to dispaly.

Comment: Hello, @Raghavender can you provide the code for this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom imageview class for Pinch zoom image view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
/**
*
* @author Vinil.S
*
*/
public class RiktamImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public RiktamImageView(Context context) {
super(context);
sharedConstructing(context);
}

public RiktamImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
super.setClickable(true);
this.context = context;
mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
matrix = new Matrix();
m = new float[9];
setImageMatrix(matrix);
setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
last.set(curr);
start.set(last);
mode = DRAG;
break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
if (mode == DRAG) {
float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
origWidth * saveScale);
float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
origHeight * saveScale);
matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
fixTrans();
last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
}
break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
mode = NONE;
int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
performClick();
break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
mode = NONE;
break;
}

setImageMatrix(matrix);
invalidate();
return true; // indicate event was handled
}

});
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
@Override
public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
mode = ZOOM;
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
float origScale = saveScale;
saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
if (saveScale > maxScale) {
saveScale = maxScale;
mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
} else if (saveScale < minScale) {
saveScale = minScale;
mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
}

if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
|| origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
viewHeight / 2);
else
matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

fixTrans();
return true;
}
}

void fixTrans() {
matrix.getValues(m);
float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
* saveScale);

if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
float minTrans, maxTrans;

if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
minTrans = 0;
maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
} else {
minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
maxTrans = 0;
}

if (trans < minTrans)
return -trans + minTrans;
if (trans > maxTrans)
return -trans + maxTrans;
return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
return 0;
}
return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

//
// Rescales image on rotation
//
if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
|| viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
return;
oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

if (saveScale == 1) {
// Fit to screen.
float scale;

Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
|| drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
return;
int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

// Center the image
float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
- (scale * (float) bmHeight);
float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
- (scale * (float) bmWidth);
redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
fixTrans();
}
}
```

Comment: The answer and easy solution

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries which you can implement pinch to zoom. Please check out the web.

Answer (score -2):

**[Here](https://gist.github.com/anorth/9845602)** is the class which enables zoom/pinch in android framelayout.

**Code:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

 /**
 * Layout that provides pinch-zooming of content. This view should have exactly one child
 * view containing the content.
 */
public class ZoomLayout extends FrameLayout implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

  private enum Mode {
    NONE,
    DRAG,
    ZOOM
  }

  private static final String TAG = "ZoomLayout";
  private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
  private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 4.0f;

  private Mode mode = Mode.NONE;
  private float scale = 1.0f;
  private float lastScaleFactor = 0f;

  // Where the finger first  touches the screen
  private float startX = 0f;
  private float startY = 0f;

  // How much to translate the canvas
  private float dx = 0f;
  private float dy = 0f;
  private float prevDx = 0f;
  private float prevDy = 0f;

  public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
  }

  public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
  }

  public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
  }

  private void init(Context context) {
    final ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
    this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i(TAG, "DOWN");
            if (scale > MIN_ZOOM) {
              mode = Mode.DRAG;
              startX = motionEvent.getX() - prevDx;
              startY = motionEvent.getY() - prevDy;
            }
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
              dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
              dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;
            }
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            mode = Mode.ZOOM;
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = Mode.DRAG;
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i(TAG, "UP");
            mode = Mode.NONE;
            prevDx = dx;
            prevDy = dy;
            break;
        }
        scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

        if ((mode == Mode.DRAG && scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
          getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
          float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
          float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale))/ 2 * scale;
          dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
          dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
          Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
            + ", max " + maxDx);
          applyScaleAndTranslation();
        }

        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  // ScaleGestureDetector

  @Override
  public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onScaleBegin");
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
    float scaleFactor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();
    Log.i(TAG, "onScale" + scaleFactor);
    if (lastScaleFactor == 0 || (Math.signum(scaleFactor) == Math.signum(lastScaleFactor))) {
      scale *= scaleFactor;
      scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));
      lastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    } else {
      lastScaleFactor = 0;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onScaleEnd");
  }

  private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
    child().setScaleX(scale);
    child().setScaleY(scale);
    child().setTranslationX(dx);
    child().setTranslationY(dy);
  }

  private View child() {
    return getChildAt(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: i am trying to use this layout.  Since this is a framelayout, I placed couple more textviews on top of the picture, which are supposed to zoom at the same scale as the imageview. But the rate of zoom for textview isn't same as that for imageview. Appreciate any guidance.